# Retrieving data from SQL Server error

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have connected to a SQL server within an Access 2010 databse. But I need to retrieve a string from the server. When I run the program I get the error message **Invalid object name 'dbo_b_Pulp_PI_Forte'.** when the program hits `run.ExecuteReader()`. I cannot find the problem. Here is my code:

```
    Dim myCmd As String
    Dim strConn1 As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim CmdCommand As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    'Connection string for SQL Server.
    strConn1.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=THIPSQLW01;Database=wss_Test;Uid=baletrack;Pwd=BaleTrack;"

    'SQL statement for SQL Server.
    myCmd = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo_b_Pulp_PI_Forte WHERE Mill = '850' and Pulp_Line_id = '" & stBaleLine & "' ORDER BY keyprinter_datetime DESC, bale_id DESC"

    'Open server.
    strConn1.Open()

    Dim run = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    'Using the SQL statement in the SQL server.
    run = New OleDbCommand(myCmd, strConn1)
    run.ExecuteReader()
```

Comment: `dbo_b_Pulp_PI_Forte` should probably be `dbo.b_Pulp_PI_Forte`

Comment: why do you think that? `bdo_b_Pulp_PI_Forte` is the name of my table inside the database.

Comment: dbo. is a default schema for db's in modern versions of sql server, so it seemed the likely problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
   'SQL statement for SQL Server.
        myCmd = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo_b_Pulp_PI_Forte 
        WHERE Mill = '850' and Pulp_Line_id = '" & stBaleLine & "' 
        ORDER BY keyprinter_datetime DESC, bale_id DESC"
```

to

```
   'SQL statement for SQL Server.
        myCmd = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.b_Pulp_PI_Forte 
        WHERE Mill = '850' and Pulp_Line_id = '" & stBaleLine & "' 
        ORDER BY keyprinter_datetime DESC, bale_id DESC"
```

**dbo** is the schema name and should be separated from the table name by a period

Comment: This solved my problem. Although It shows a different problem later on in my code, but solved the problem I was stuck on. Thank you.